# How to know if two classes implement a common interface?

Tags: java, oop, elasticsearch, kotlin

Is there an easy way to check if two classes implement a common interface? 
I am using IntelliJ, and calling a Java library (Elastic Java High Level REST Client) from some Kotlin code.

`SearchHit` and `GetResponse` classes both have `getId()` and `getSourceAsString()` methods. How can I know if they implement a common interface, so that I can mutualize my functions that take these objects as parameters ?

This is my code :

```
    fun JsonAdapter<Descriptor>.fromHit(hit: SearchHit): Descriptor {
        val descriptor = this.fromJson(hit.sourceAsString)
        if (descriptor == null) {
            throw BadFormatException("Json descriptorDeserializer returned a null value")
        }

        descriptor.descriptorId = hit.id
        return descriptor
    }

    fun JsonAdapter<Descriptor>.fromResponse(response: GetResponse): Descriptor {
        val descriptor = this.fromJson(response.sourceAsString)
        if (descriptor == null) {
            throw BadFormatException("Json descriptorDeserializer returned a null value")
        }

        descriptor.descriptorId = response.id
        return descriptor
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run Time

You can try the `is` keyword in **Kotlin** to check if an object is an instance of some **interfaces**:

```
if (obj is MyInterface) {...}
```

Which is the Kotlin equivalent of the **Java**:

```
if (obj instanceof MyInterface) {
    //...
}
```

## During Development

During development with `Intellij Idea`, we can quickly check `classes` declaration by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>B</kbd>  when the cursor is on the class name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My need is to identify the interfaces during development (and not at runtime)

Comment: @Gelineau You're welcome. If you need to quickly check which `interfaces` is implementing a `class`, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know which interface is implemented by your classes you can use the following code to get a list of these interfaces. You'll get a list of classes that you can compare do see if your objects share a common interface.

```
val obj = MyClass()   
var interfaces = obj.javaClass.interfaces
```

Comment: It works, thanks.

Unfortunately, it seems that the two methods that I am calling are not part of the common interface.